# Prove this trig identity: $A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \cos(\omega t - \arctan(\tfrac{B}{A}))$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble proving the following identity:

$$A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} \cos(\omega t - \arctan(\tfrac{B}{A}))$$

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta=\omega t$ and $C=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $\alpha=\arctan\frac{B}{A}$.

Since $\cos\alpha=\frac{A}{C}$ and $\sin\alpha=\frac{B}{C}$, we get that

$\cos(\theta-\alpha)=\cos\theta\cos\alpha+\sin\theta\sin\alpha=\frac{A}{C}\cos\theta+\frac{B}{C}\sin\theta$, so

$C\cos(\theta-\alpha)=A\cos\theta+B\sin\theta$.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.